# what is the most lightweight solution to repeatedly access html element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

regarding html elements that are being referenced frequently in code, such as a menu that is being shown/hidden often, what is the most lightweight jquery solution to re-access the element multiple times?

my current approach is to save the result in a variable (non global of course).

example:

```
$myElement = $('#my-element');
```

then use `$myElement` rather than `$('#my-element')` in all code that running withtin he scope of the variable.

another approach I am using is the $.data() method. I use this when I need to access one element based on another.

example:

```
$myElement.data('friend', $('my-element-friend'));
```

then use `$myElement.data('friend')` instead of  `$('my-element-friend')`

Are there other options to consider?
Are there cases where its best to simply repeat `$('#my-element')` each time that I wish to access the element? (aside from when the reference is only used once in the entire runtime of the application)

Answer (score 1):

Storing a reference in a variable (such as it is) is a good approach.

The only time I'd always use a selector is if the element in question is being destroyed/recreated all the time. Or if you are accessing a collection of elements that is changing between the calls (think `$( '.SomeClass' )`).

Comment: thanks. apparently the .data function is a safe approach as well. as stated here: http://api.jquery.com/data/  " The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks. "